# How to use spring bean in Hibernate UserType?

Tags: spring, hibernate

```
public class DictType implements UserType, ParameterizedType {
    private String type;
    @Inject
    private CommonHibernateDao dao;
    setter;
    getter;
...
```

When I use dao, a `NullPointException` will throw

Comment: have you created bean to the class CommonHibernateDao?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you created the bean CommonHibernateDao annotated with @Repository and scanning the package containing CommonHibernateDao in your application context.

Comment: yes,  the problem is the UserType Used by hibernate not spring.

Comment: What I understand is you are merging the Service layer and Dao Layer in a single class, is it correct?